# What are the major examples of Brahman or Sage became King in Hinduism?

Tags: dharma, rishi, brahmins, varna, kings

In Hindu Varna system, politics, war and ruling the kingdom is Dharma of Kshatriya. Similarly, Dharma of Brahman is to learn, teach, perform Yadnya and other vedic activities, advice the king etc.

On the other hand, Sages are quit from normal life. They are not generally interested in things like ruling the kingdom.

Are there any examples of Brahman or Sage became King (ruled the kingdom) in Hinduism?

One example I remember is Parshuram; but I am not sure if that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Brahmin_dynasties_and_states) is the list of empires made by Brahmins who crowned themselves kings.

1. Sena Empire
2. The Shunga Empire of Magadha was established By Pushyamitra Shunga[5]
3. The Kanva Dynasty replaced the Shunga Empire in Magadha and Ruled in the Eastern regions of India[6]
4. The Satavahana Dynasty - 230bc to 250ad In present day part of Madhya Pradesh, Gujrat, Maharashtra, Telangana, Rajasthan, Northern Karnataka etc[7]
5. Parivrajaka Dynasty Ruled parts of Central India during the 5th and 6th centuries. The kings of this Dynasty bore the title Maharaja, and probably Ruled as feudatories of the Gupta Empire. The royal Family came from a Lineage of Brahmins of Bharadwaj Gotra.[8]
6. Kadamba Dynasty (345 – 525 CE) was a Dynasty that Ruled Northern Karnataka and the Konkan from Banavasi in present-day Uttara Kannada district[9]
7. Pallava Dynasty {c.285 -905 CE} was a Tamil brahmin of bharadwaj gotra (Tamil Samaṇar Dynasty), Pallavas Ruled Andhra (Krishna-Guntur) and North and Central Tamil Nadu. Appar is traditionally credited with converting the Pallava king, Mahendravarman to Saivaism.[10][11]
8. The Oiniwar Dynasty, based in Mithila were Maithil Brahmins[12][13]
9. Vakataka Dynasty was a Dynasty from the Indian subcontinent that is believed to have extended from the southern edges of Malwa and Gujarat in the North to the Tungabhadra River in the South as well as from the Arabian Sea in the West to the edges of Chhattisgarh in the East[14]
10. Brahman Dynasty of Sindh was founded By Chach of Alor, later Ruled By Chandar of Sindh and Raja Dahir
11. Bhurshut Dynasty was a medieval Hindu Dynasty spread across what is now Howrah and Hooghly districts in the Indian state of West Bengal;which was Ruled By a Royal Brahmin Family
12. Baghochia Dynasty was founded By Raja Bir Sen and were the ruling Dynasty of Hathwa Raj and Bans Gaon Estate. The Cadet branch of the Family also Ruled Tamkuhi Raj, Salemgarh Estate, Ledo Gadi, Kiajori estate and Kharna Ghatwali.Bhumihar dynasty
13. Kabul Shahi Dynasty belonged to Bali clan of Mohyal Brahmin
14. Aryacakravarti Dynasty which was Ruled By Tamil Brahmins
15. Peshwai, Peshwas were Brahmin and were the De facto rulers of Maratha Empire
16. Patwardhan Dynasty was an Indian Dynasty established By the Chitpavan Brahmin Patwardhan Family
17. Aundh State, Ruled By Deshasthas Brahmins
18. Bhor State, a 9 gun Salute princely state Ruled By Deshasthas Brahmins
19. Gaurihar State of Madhya Pradesh Ruled By Deshasthas Brahmins
20. Jalaun State of Bundelkhand region Ruled By a Deshasthas Brahmins
21. Jhansi State Ruled By Newelkar House of Karhades Brahmins
22. Jamkhandi State Ruled By Chitpavans Brahmins
23. Ramdurg State Ruled By Chitpavans Brahmins
24. Miraj Junior and Miraj Senior states were Ruled By Chitpavans Brahmins
25. Kurundvad Senior and Kurundvad Junior states were rulered By Patwardhan clan of Chitpavans Brahmins
26. Sangli State, an 11 gun Salute princely state Ruled By Chitpavans Brahmins
27. Panth-Piploda Province a province of British India Ruled By a Deshasthas Brahmins
28. Chaube Jagirs were a group of five feudatory princely states of Central India during the period of the British Raj. which were Ruled By different branches of Brahmin Family.
29. Benares State, a 13 gun salute (15 gun salute local) state Ruled By Bhumihar Brahmins
30. Arni estate was a jagir in the erstwhile Madras Presidency which was Ruled By Deshasthas Brahmins
31. Yelandur estate was a jagir in the erstwhile Mysore State which was Ruled By Madhwas Brahmins
32. Baudh State was a princely state Ruled By a Brahmin Family who adopted as successor a nephew of the Raja of Keonjhar
33. Darbhanga Raj of Mithila, Bihar - Ruled By Maithil Brahmins
34. Singhwara Estate of Mithila, Bihar - Ruled By Maithil Brahmins
35. Rajshahi Raj of Bengal - Ruled By Rajshahi Family - (Varendra Brahmins)
36. Banaili Estate of Bihar - Ruled By Chaudhary Bahadhur Lineage - (Maithil Brahmins)
37. Bhawal Estate of Bengal - Ruled By Choudhary Lineage - (Shrotriya Brahmin)
38. Nadia Raj of Bengal - Ruled By Roy or Ray Lineage - (Kulin Brahmins)
39. Dighapatia Raj of Bengal - Ruled By Roy Lineage - (Varendra Brahmins)
40. Muktagacha Raj of Bengal - Ruled By Chowdhary Lineage - (Varendra Brahmins)[1]
41. Vishalgad Estate of the British Raj - Ruled By Pant Prathinidhi Family - (Deshastha Brahmins)
42. Ichalkaranji Estate of the British Raj - Ruled By Joshi Family - (Chitpavan Brahmins)
43. Yelandur Estate of Mysore Kingdom - Ruled By Madhwa Brahmin Family.
44. Panyam Zamindari of Madras Presidency - Ruled By Deshastha Brahmins
45. Arni Estate of Madras Presidency - Ruled By Deshastha Brahmins
46. Bettiah Raj Ruled By Bhumihar Brahmins
47. Natore Raj of Bengal - Ruled By Roy Lineage - (Varendra Brahmin)[15]
48. Tekari Raj of Bihar - Ruled By Bhumihar Brahmins
49. Zamindari of Ratangarh (Bijnore) Ruled By Taga Rao Zokha Singh Tyagi Atri - He was a former commander (or Rao) of the northern branch of the Maratha Confederate Army, whose control ranged to the Tarai baselands of the Himalayas, Family of Chaudhry Lineage - Tyagi Gaur Brahmins
    Ruled by Jamnapar Dilli dehat (Choudhary lineage) Dikshit Tyagi (Choudhary Musaib khan) during Bahadur shah zafar 1857 revolt
50. Karnat dynasty - Ruled By - (Bikauwa Brahmins)